# can't download pdf files with Capybara and Mechanize

Tags: ruby, capybara, mechanize

I have a ruby application which tries to download about 40 pdf files,using Capybara and Mechanize:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agnet.get("https://site.com/file.pdf")
```

When I get to the 25th pdf file I get the following error:

```
crawling done, failed with Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error: too many connection resets     (due to Timeout::Error - Timeout::Error) after 0 requests on 106051380, last used 1350327629.8242197 seconds ago
```

Can you tell me what can I do in order to go on downloading?

Edit: I have posted more code, and I can tell you now that it doesn't always happens when I try to download the 25th file, it's sometimes the 10th file, and sometimes the sixth file (so the bug is not for a specific file)

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: We need a lot more information to be able to help you.

Comment: OK. I am editing my question and adding some more information and code... @SunnyJuneja

Comment: You need to add even more... are you doing Mechanize.new for every single site?

Comment: no, it's a loop that uses the same agent for each file (the files are on the server..) @SunnyJuneja